# why this https request only works with urllib3 and requests libraries?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

I'm making this request and it only works with urllib3 and requests library i'm guessing it's because of ssl version or cert verification. any clue would be appreciated

this works

```py
import urllib3

params = {...}
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_NONE', assert_hostname=False)
r = http.request("POST", "https://android.clients.google.com/auth" , fields=params)
print(r.data)
```

this return `Error=BadAuthentication`

```py
from urllib import request, parse
import urllib

params = {...}
data = parse.urlencode(params).encode()
req = request.Request("https://android.clients.google.com/auth", data=data)
try:
  resp = request.urlopen(req)
  print(resp.read())
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
  print("error", e.read())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a problem with ciphers using this code worked for me

```py
from urllib import request, parse
import urllib
import ssl

params = {...}

data = parse.urlencode(params).encode()
req = request.Request("https://android.clients.google.com/auth" , data=data) # this will make the method "POST"

DEFAULT_CIPHERS = ':'.join([
    'TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384',
    'TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256',
    'TLS13-AES-128-GCM-SHA256',
    'ECDH+AESGCM',
    'ECDH+CHACHA20',
    'DH+AESGCM',
    'DH+CHACHA20',
    'ECDH+AES256',
    'DH+AES256',
    'ECDH+AES128',
    'DH+AES',
    'RSA+AESGCM',
    'RSA+AES',
    '!aNULL',
    '!eNULL',
])

ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext()
if getattr(ssl_context, 'supports_set_ciphers', True):  # Platform-specific: Python 2.6
    ssl_context.set_ciphers(DEFAULT_CIPHERS)

try:
  resp = request.urlopen(req, context=ssl_context)
  print(resp.read())
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
  print("error", e.read())
```